# tbody cant work in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Why my tbody is not doing what I want, anyone can help me ?

This is my problem, in case I want to display in row but why that value just stay in column 1.2:
[image]

This is my jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://swapi.co/api/people/',
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      var counter = 0;
      var obj = response.results;
      var Content = ' ';
      var x = 0;

      Content += '<tbody>'; //opening tag tbody
      for(var i=0;i<obj.length; i++)
      {
          Content += '<tr>';
          Content += '<td>'+obj[i].name+'</td>';
          Content += '<td>'+obj[i].height+'</td>';
          Content += '<td>'+obj[i].hair_color+'</td>';
          Content += '<td>'+obj[i].skin_color+'</td>';
          Content += '<td>'+obj[i].eye_color+'</td>';
          Content += '<td>'+obj[i].birth_year+'</td>';
          Content += '<td>'+obj[i].gender+'</td>'
          Content += '</tr>';
      }
      Content += '</tbody>'; 
      $('#results').empty(); 
      $('#results').append(Content); 
    }
  });
});

var tbody=document.getElementById("results");
var table=document.getElementById("tableId");
var tbodyIndex= [].slice.call(table.tBodies).indexOf(tbody);
```

And this my html

```
<table class="table table-stripted table-bordered table-hover" id="tableId">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Height</th>
            <th>Hair Color</th>
            <th>Skin Color</th>
            <th>Eye Color</th>
            <th>Birth Year</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="results">

    </tbody>
</table>
```

please help me , im newbie in javascript, oh yeah sorry for bad grammer, hope u guys help me , thank you

Comment: Seems like `#results` is already a `<tbody>` and you're appending another `<tbody>` to the end of it. Can you include the HTML that is rendered from this code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The HTML generated by your code is below.
Notice the two nested `<tbody>` elements, which disrupts the layout of your table.

**GENERATED HTML**

```html
<table class="table table-stripted table-bordered table-hover " id="tableId">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Height</th>
      <th>Hair Color</th>
      <th>Skin Color</th>
      <th>Eye Color</th>
      <th>Birth Year</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="results">
    <tbody>

      <tr>
        <td>Luke Skywalker</td>
        <td>172</td>
        <td>blond</td>
        <td>fair</td>
        <td>blue</td>
        <td>19BBY</td>
        <td>male</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

As Maarten van Tjonger has already answered, remove `<tbody>` from your `Content` string to avoid its duplication.

Rather than using `empty()` and `append()`, I've used [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to replace the contents of the `<tbody>` with the new HTML.

Also, you'll want to execute `dataTable()` on the `<table>` itself, not the `<tbody>`.

**WORKING EXAMPLE**

```js
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://swapi.co/api/people/',
    success: function(response) {

      var obj = response.results,
        Content;

      for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        Content += '<tr>';
        Content += '<td>' + obj[i].name + '</td>';
        Content += '<td>' + obj[i].height + '</td>';
        Content += '<td>' + obj[i].hair_color + '</td>';
        Content += '<td>' + obj[i].skin_color + '</td>';
        Content += '<td>' + obj[i].eye_color + '</td>';
        Content += '<td>' + obj[i].birth_year + '</td>';
        Content += '<td>' + obj[i].gender + '</td>'
        Content += '</tr>';
      }

      $('#results').html(Content);
      $('#tableId').dataTable();

    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table class="table table-stripted table-bordered table-hover " id="tableId">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Height</th>
      <th>Hair Color</th>
      <th>Skin Color</th>
      <th>Eye Color</th>
      <th>Birth Year</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="results">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add a tbody tag when your ajax response come in.
It's already in the DOM.
You can remove:

```
Content += '<tbody>'; 
Content += '</tbody>';
```

Answer (score -3):

You are missing the quotes around your tbody id `<tbody id=results>` should be `<tbody id="results">` and you are generating a second `<tbody>` in your JS which is not necessary. Otherwise your code runs fine so see this [fiddle with the problems corrected.](https://jsfiddle.net/a1180m47/2/)

Comment: Look at the column in the name, it's a mess I mean that object must match the raw

Comment: Just check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a1180m47/2/) the second problem was the additional <tbody> you were adding as noted in one of the other answers.